# What is the corresponding function for the infinite taylor series expansion of summing infinite k-terms of x^-k

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^k}$$

How would you find f(x), and what are some tips/tricks to think about converting/discovering the function form that an infinite series is trying to show (or perhaps elaborate on the thought process for this question)? Thanks in advance

Comment: In this particular case, it's basically one you either already know, or you don't. Very, very few people figure this one out on their own. Not really because it's difficult, but because the solution is down to them before they get the chance.

Comment: One thing I want to point out is that the sum should run over $k$ rather than $i$. Another thing is that does this series look familiar? The terms are getting multiplied by $\frac{1}{x}$ every time. Can you think of what this series is and how do we find its sum? Also, under what conditions can you actually find the sum? Hint: Try putting in values of $x$ such as $1, -1, 2, \frac{1}{2}$ and other simple things. Try to observe something.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical geometric serie. For $x = 0$ the limit is clear, let us see what happens when $x \neq 0$. First set $y = x^{-1}$ so that our serie becomes
$$g(y) = f(1/y) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty y^k.$$
We set
$$S_n = 1 + y + y^2 + \ldots + y^n,$$
such that
$$yS_n = y + y^2 + \ldots + y^n + y^{n+1} = S_n - 1 + y^{n+1},$$
which gives us
$$S_n\left(y - 1\right) = y^{n+1} - 1 \quad \overset{y \neq 1}{\Leftrightarrow} \quad S_n = \frac{y^{n+1} - 1}{y - 1}.$$
We see that
$$g(y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$$
which converges if and only if $|y| < 1$ and the limit is
$$\frac{1}{1 - y}.$$

Comment: I didn't realize this was a geometric series after thinking along the lines of Taylor Series expansion for a long while, thank you for the reply! :)